# List of objects from text file

Tags: c#, list, text-files

After much regex cleanup (thanks SO!), I now have code that takes a specific text file, cleans out all the junk and weird formatting, and results in the following:

```
...
NAME:John Smith
TITILE:Mr
BUILDING:A
NAME:Jane Smith
TITLE:Miss
BUILDING:CX
...
```

for several thousand employees.

I also have a class Employee that has Properties - you guessed it - Name, Title and Building.

Right now I parse the file line by line and create new instances of Employee with the relevant text that comes after "PROPERTY:", which I then add to a list, but I can't shake the feeling that such a perfect match between text input and class description could lend itself to a piece of c# magic to do take my text and create my list of Employee objects all in an elegant one-liner (or even 10-liner). Any advice or pointers?

Comment: well it isn't Json or Xml so you'll need to manually parse it.  I think your approach is fine

Comment: I agree with Jonesy, you could always wrap the parsing into an elegant call, but seems like you're going to have to parse somewhere

Comment: If you gotta parse, you gotta parse.

Comment: Even with parsing line by line it doesn't seem to be much more than 10 lines. Trying to do this in one line seems to me to be wanting to be clever just for being clever.

Comment: You could use reflection to cut down on some of the manual stuff.  I could see this being useful if you might add fields in the future and not want to modify your parsing code.

Comment: Thanks guys - just trying to learn more about c#, and very impressed with how elegant the code tends to be. However, If parsing is needed here, then so be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to make it more generic I would do the following:

When you read each property use reflection to find the value in the class

```
Employee e = new Employee();
PropertyInfo property = typeof(Employee).GetProperty(strProperty);
property.SetValue(e, propertyValue);
```

Now this could get really expensive if you're reflecting on the class with each line of the file you read in, but you can get around that by building a dictionary to hold your properties at the beginning:

```
Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> properties = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();

for each (PropertyInfo p in typeof(Employee).GetProperties)
    properties.Add(p.Name, p);
```

Then when you're looping through your file you just call:

```
Employee e = new Employee();

properties[strProperty].SetValue(e, propertyValue);
```

Dapper (the object mapper used here at SO I believe) works in a similar fashion.

**Edit**

If you have public fields along with properties, you'll have to loop through them as well:

```
Dictionary<string, FieldInfo> fields = new Dictionary<string, FieldInfo>();

for each (FieldInfo f in typeof(Employee).GetFields)
    fields.Add(f.Name, f);
```

Additionaly, if you want to limit or expand the scope of indexed properties/fields, or include properties and fields of sub classes, use [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[GetFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(BindingFlags)

Comment: Thanks - not exactly what I was hoping for (but happy enough that I was hoping for too much), but this has certainly taught me something new that I can definitely use.